# Mourners prayers that we say at the funeral

Tags: minhag, mourning-aveilus

Is there a place I can get the prayers that we say at a funeral online so I can print it out. It's an Ashkenazi funeral also if anyone has one with both Hebrew and English that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chabad.org has [The Basics of the Jewish Funeral](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/282505/jewish/Soul-Talk.htm)

> The Burial ("Kevurah"). We return the body to the earth that is its
>   source. This is our final act of caring, and it is considered a great
>   mitzvah to physically participate in the burial. Ideally, the whole
>   grave should be filled in, by hand, by fellow Jews. Where this is not
>   possible, at least the coffin should be completely covered with earth.
>   At this point, Tzidduk Hadin is recited--a series of verses
>   acknowledging G‑d's just ways even as we confront tragedy. We then
>   recite the Kaddish and the El Malei Rachamim memorial prayer. (Click
>   here for the texts of [Tzidduk
>   Hadin](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/387093/jewish/Tziduk-HaDin.htm),
>   the
>   [Kaddish](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371111/jewish/Kaddish.htm)
>   and [El Malei
>   Rachamim](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/387078/jewish/Kel-Maleh-Rachamim.htm))

Chabad.org also says that at [the Burial](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/368092/jewish/The-Burial.htm)

> The casket is carried from the hearse to the gravesite by Jewish men,
>   usually by the Chevra Kaddisha, with the decedent's feet facing the
>   front. It is customary that direct descendants of the deceased do not
>   touch or carry the casket.
>
> During the procession, Psalm 91 is recited seven times. Beginning from
>   a short distance from the grave (approximately thirty feet), it is
>   customary to halt the procession every few feet and repeat the Psalm,
>   pausing at certain words in the final verse and reciting again from
>   the top.
>
> Before the casket is lowered into the grave, it is fitting to part with
>   the deceased and, if one has not done so earlier at the memorial
>   service, ask for forgiveness (and to forgive) for any pain or hard
>   feelings that might have come between them.
>
> Following the recitation of certain Psalms and prayers, the casket is
>   laid in the grave by the Chevra Kaddisha. It is set in the direction
>   so that the deceased's head rests where the tombstone will be erected,
>   and the feet are positioned to the front of the grave. It is then
>   covered with earth and the grave is filled until a small mound is
>   formed on top. This is followed by the recitation of "Tziduk Hadin,"
>   and the Mourner's Kaddish.
>
> The Chevra Kaddisha sprinkles earth from the Land of Israel into the
>   grave, as the land is holy. All the men present then fill the grave
>   with earth, beginning by covering the upper part of the casket. The
>   men can take turns, but the shovel must not be passed directly from
>   one person to the next. Instead, it is placed face down on the ground,
>   and the next person takes it, to show that this is not "regular" work.
>
> Some have the custom that members of the Chevra Kaddisha begin the
>   filling of the grave by scooping earth in their hands and delicately
>   placing it on the casket until it is completely covered, followed by
>   everyone else with shovels.
>
> As one fills the grave with earth, recite the following verse three
>   times:
>
> והוא רחום יכפר עוןולא ישחית והרבא להשיב אפו ולא יאיר כל חמתו
>
> He, being compassionate, pardons iniquity, and does not destroy; time and
>   again He turns away His anger, and does not arouse all His
>   wrath.
>
> It is highly preferable for Jewish men to fill in the grave. In the
>   case where there are not enough men for this task, the casket must be
>   at least completely covered with earth before allowing cemetery
>   workers to finish the job.
>
> Tziduk Hadin & Psalm 49
>
> Once the grave is completely filled with earth and the top is in the
>   shape of a small mound, a marker is placed on the grave with the name
>   of the deceased and date of passing. The prayer of "Tziduk Hadin" is
>   then recited. With this deeply meaningful prayer the mourners declare
>   their acceptance of G‑d's decree and pray to G‑d to have mercy upon
>   those who are living.
>
> (If Tachnun is not recited on that day, we omit "Tziduk Hadin," and
>   proceed directly with Psalm 49. This also applies for a burial on late
>   Friday afternoon, or on Erev Yom Tov -- a day leading into a Jewish
>   holiday.)

Aramaic and transliteration [The Graveside Mourner's Kaddish](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/368097/jewish/The-Graveside-Kaddish.htm)

Aramaic and translation into English [Burial Kaddish (Ashkenazim)](http://www.jewish-funeral-guide.com/tradition/burial-kaddish-ashkenazi.htm)

יִתְגַּדַּל ‏[‏נ״א׃ יִתְגַּדֵּל‏]‏
וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ ‏[‏נ״א׃ וְיִתְקַדֵּשׁ‏]‏
שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא

Exalted
and sanctified
be His great name

הקהל׃אָמֵן

בְּעָלְמָא דִּי הוּא ‏[‏נ״א׃ דּהוּא‏]‏ עָתִיד
לְאִתְחַדְתָּא

וּלְאַחֲיָאה מֵתַיָּא

congregation responds:Amen

In the world that in the future
[will] be renewed,

and [where] He will revive the dead,

‏ ‏יש מוסיפים׃
‏[‏וּלְאַסָּקָא יַתְּהוֹן לְחַיֵּי עָלְמָא‏]‏

לְמִבְנָא קַרְתָּא דִּי יְרוּשְלֵם
וּלְשַׁכְלְלָא הֵיכָלֵהּ בְּגַוָּהּ

‏ ‏נוסח אחר׃
‏[‏וּלְשַׁכְלְלָא הֵיכָלֵהּ ולְמִפרַק חַיַיָא
וּלְמִבְנָא קַרְתָּא דִּירוּשְלֵם‏]‏

וּלְמֶעֱקַר פּוּלְחָנָא נוּכְרָאָה
מִן אַרְעָה וּלְאָתָבָא
פּוּלְחָנָא דִּי שְׁמַיָּא לְאַתְרָהּ
וְיַמְלִיך קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא
בּמַלְכוּתֵה וִיקָרֵהּ

‏ ‏נוסח אחר׃
‏[‏וּלְמֶעֱקַר פּוּלְחָנָא נוּכְרָאָה
מִן אַרְעָה וּלְאָתָבָא
פּוּלְחָנָא קַדִּישָה דִּשְׁמַיָּא
לְאַתְרֵהּ‏,‏ וֵזִיוֵהּ
וִיקָרֵהּ וּשְׁכִנְתֵּהּ‏]‏

some add:
[and raise them up to eternal life]

rebuild the city of Jerusalem
and establish His Temple in it;

alternatively:
[and establish His Temple, deliver life,
and rebuild the city of Jerusalem]

uproot alien worship
from the world and restore
the service of Heaven to its place,
and may the Holy One Blessed is He reign
in His sovereignty and His splendor

alternatively:
[uproot alien worship from
the world and restore
the holy service of Heaven
to its place, along with its radiance,
glory and holy presence]

‏ ‏יש מוסיפים׃
‏[‏וְיַצְמַח פֻּרְקָנֵה
וִיקָרֵב מְשִׁיחֵהּ׃

הקהל׃אָמֵן‏]‏

בְּחַיֵּיכוֹן וּבְיוֹמֵיכוֹן
וּבְחַיֵּי דְכָל בֵּית
יִשְׂרָאֵל‏,‏ בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב
‏-‏ וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן׃

some add:
[and may He bring forth His redemption
and hasten the coming of His Messiah.

and congregation responds:Amen]

in your lifetime and in your days
and within the life of the entire House of
Israel, speedily and in the near future
- and let’s say to it, Amen.

‏ ‏הקהל עונים׃
אָמֵן‏,‏ יְהֵא שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא מְבָרַךְ
לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא׃
יש מוסיפים׃ ‏[‏יִתְבָּרַךְ‏]‏
ויש ממשיכים עד ‏[... ‏בְּרִיךְ הוּא‏]‏

‏ ‏האבלים ממשיכים׃
יְהֵא שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא מְבָרַךְ
לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא׃

יִתְבָּרַךְ ‏[‏נ״א׃ יִתְבָּרֵךְ‏]‏ וְיִשְׁתַּבַּח
וְיִתְפָּאַר ‏[‏נ״א׃ וְיִתְפָּאֵר‏]‏ וְיִתְרוֹמַם
וְיִתְנַשֵּׂא וְיִתְהַדָּר וְיִתְעַלֶּה וְיִתְהַלָּל
שְׁמֵהּ דְּקֻדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא׃

congregation responds:
Amen, May His great name be blessed
forever and ever!
some start next paragraph: [Blessed]
and some continue until [... blessed be He]

mourners continue:
May His great name be blessed
forever and ever!

Blessed and praised,
glorified and exalted,
uplifted, honored, elevated and lauded be
the name of the Holy One, blessed be He.

הקהל׃בְּרִיךְ הוּא
נוסח אחר׃ ‏[‏אָמֵן‏]‏

לְעֵלָּא מִן כָּל בִּרְכָתָא

congregation responds:Blessed be He
alternatively: [Amen]

beyond any blessing

‏ ‏בעשרת ימי תשובה יש אומרים׃
‏[‏לְעֵלָּא ‏(‏נ״א׃ וּ‏)‏לְעֵלָּא מִכָּל בִּרְכָתָא‏]‏

וְשִׁירָתָא‏,‏ תֻּשְׁבְּחָתָא וְנֶחֱמָתָא‏,‏
דַּאֲמִירָן בְּעָלְמָא
‏-‏ וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן׃

הקהל׃אָמֵן

between Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur
some substitute [far beyond any blessing]

and hymn, praise and consolation
that is ever spoken in the world
- and let’s say to it, Amen.

congregation responds:Amen

[During a Siyum / סיום, the Rabbis' Kaddish segment is inserted here.]

יְהֵא שְׁלָמָא רַבָּא
מִן שְׁמַיָּא

וְחַיִּים יש מוסיפים׃ ‏[‏טובים‏]‏
עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל

May there be abundant peace
from Heaven

and life some say: [good life]
for us and for all Israel

‏-‏ וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן׃

הקהל׃אָמֵן

- and let’s say to it, Amen.

congregation responds:Amen

‏ ‏פוסעים שלוש פסיעות לאחור ואומרים׃
עוֹשֶׂה
‏ ‏בעשרת ימי תשובה
יש מוסיפים׃ ‏[‏הַ‏]‏שָּׁלוֹם בִּמְרוֹמָיו

הוּא יש מוסיפים׃ ‏[‏בְּרַחֲמָיו‏]‏ יַעֲשֶׂה
שָׁלוֹם עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל
‏-‏ וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן׃

הקהל׃אָמֵן

mourners take 3 steps back, and say:
He who makes
between Rosh HaShanah and Yom Kippur
some add: [the] peace on high,

may He some add: [in His mercy] make
peace for us and for all Israel
- and let’s say to it, Amen.

congregation responds:Amen